# Git Push Error: Unable to persist credentials with the 'wincredman' credential store

Tags: c#, .net, git, azure-devops, repository

I'm using .NET to run a task that commits and pushes changes to a git repository on Azure, but I'm getting the error:

```
fatal: Unable to persist credentials with the 'wincredman' credential store.
See https://aka.ms/gcm/credstores for more information.
```

When I try to do the final git command I need to do:
`git push origin main`

I also get:

```
Cygwin WARNING:
Couldnt compute FAST_CWD pointer. This typically occurs if youre using
an older Cygwin version on a newer Windows. Please update to the latest
available Cygwin version from https://cygwin.com/. If the problem persists,
please see https://cygwin.com/problems.html
```

before
and

```
error: failed to execute prompt script (exit code 1)
fatal: could not read Username for 'https://[company].visualstudio.com': No such file or directory
```

after

but I do not believe that's causing the problem.

My commands are:

```
("PowerShell"); //so it can cd to the webshare. 

(@"cd \\[filepath]\");

(@"git add *"); //stage new files or changes

(@"git commit -m ""Daily Mainframe Repository Commit"" "); //commit changes

(@"git push origin main"); //push changes to repo

("exit");                  //Execute exit.
```

What does

fatal: Unable to persist credentials with the 'wincredman' credential store.
See https://aka.ms/gcm/credstores for more information.

mean? I've looked at [some documentation](https://github.com/git-ecosystem/git-credential-manager/blob/main/docs/credstores.md) but that doesn't really help at diagnosis. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

What user are you running as? I found this post while trying to resolve an issue I had with pushing from a command prompt. It turned out that I re-used a command prompt window which I had started as administrator.
I guess you have to run as the user that has the azure access.

Answer (score 0):

This fixed it for me under `Windows 10 x64` and `Git v2.43.0.windows.1`:

```
git config --global credential.credentialStore dpapi
```

When I switched it back to `wincredman` the same error reappeared:

```
git config --global credential.credentialStore wincredman
```

More: https://github.com/git-ecosystem/git-credential-manager/blob/main/docs/credstores.md

I was using GitHub, I also generated a remote access token and reset the upstream repo:

```
git remote set-url origin https://username:ghp_Vnc8xxxxxx@github.com/username/repo.git
```

I generated the user access token under GitHub using `[ Settings > Developer Settings > Personal Access Tokens > Tokens (classic) ]`

Answer (score -1):

> fatal: Unable to persist credentials with the 'wincredman' credential store.

My understanding of this is: it's trying to use windows default git credential manager for you to login remote git but it failed to do that. However, you don't have to use credential manager.

You can use classic ways, e.g. SSH git URI to login.
Looks like You're using Windows, I suggest to use "Git For Windows" or "Git Extensions", which all contain a Windows Bash terminal, as git cli tool instead of Cygwin.

And follow some git setup tutorials on Internet. You're using Azure git repository, so this might be helpful for you: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/repos/git/use-ssh-keys-to-authenticate?view=azure-devops